# Why doesn't Finn just use a Flame Shield spell to be more intimate with Flame Princess?

Tags: adventure-time

In the episode ["Incendium"](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Incendium), Flambo puts a Flame Shield on Jake so that Jake can go to the Fire Kingdom to meet the Flame Princess.

Whenever Finn and Flame Princess try to get intimate with each other however, it never works out (short of Finn being wrapped up in tin foil like a Chipotle burrito).

So why not just have Flambo cast a Flame Shield spell on Finn?

Comment: Maybe a flame shield is only affective on flames more than a short distance away from the body?

Comment: We find out in later episodes that Finn...Likes pain, so it's entirely possible he doesn't mind getting burned by Flame Princess as much as you'd think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it'd be too conventional. The show needs some sort of conflict. It's like how Superman has Kryptonite, IronMan needs energy, I don't quite know Hulk's weakness, but in every work there is something preventing the character from having what they want too easily.
Then again, it could be just as Chatter Humin said, Jake said "Ow" when he got spat on, indicating that the fire at that close a range was still too hot.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe he forgets about the spell when they attempt to hug or kiss I mean he has like no attention span so its very possible that he forgot about it

Comment: Also possible, but he's pretty quick to hit Flambo up for the flame shield spell when they meet again for something unrelated, so... yeh.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe Flambo stayed in the Fire Kingdom so now they can't get to him and Flame Princess doesn't know the incantation...?

Comment: Unaccepting this as an answer since he just made a reappearance in the episode "Ignition Point", and recast Flame Shield on the two of them at Finn's request.

Shenanigans!

Comment: @TerranceShaw Right? And Finn didn't even slip Flame Princess a hug on the way out!

Comment: @JasonC Exactly! More Flame Princess lovin'!

Answer (score 1):

Flambo is not always around. Jake doesn't know how to cast the flame shield incantation. Nor does he have the skills to do so.
So he just wraps Finn on tin foil to try and help him out.

It seems that this incantation can only be casted by characters that have some form of connection or intimacy with the fire element.

Comment: So why not get one of them?

Comment: The question asked why they didn't have _Flambo_ cast the Flame Shield spell on Finn.

Comment: @LogicDictates  I mean, they mentioned the tin foil. So I explained why he gets wrapped on it. Flambo is a citizen from the fire kingdom.  I thought it wasn't necessary for me to mention that he's not always with Finn and Jake. But I edited it already 

Comment: @DavidW I wonder why Flame Princess doesn't cast the spell herself. I can only think of two options: 1. Maybe because she's Finn's age, she still doesn't know how to do it; 2. The fire shield incantation is meant to repel fire from whoever the spell is cast upon. FP is pure fire. Perhaps it would repel or even hurt her if Finn touched her while wearing it. Besides that, fire ppl are rarely seen outside of the fire kingdom. Finn and Jake would need to enter the fire kingdom to find someone else to cast the spell. How will they enter without the protection spell? It's a conundrum